# Build Array based on dropdowns selected and dynamically update using computed function

Tags: arrays, data-binding, vue.js, computed-properties

I have three dropdowns which you can see in my codepen below. As I select one of these values the output array display this dropdowns associated tags which are pulled from an array.

This works perfectly but when I select the next dropdown it removes all the current values in the array and replaces with the second dropdowns values. I wan to keep the values associated with each dropdown and when each one changes the array updates to demonstrate this.

Really hope I made sense but basically I want to build an array based on the three dropdowns values selected and update this array when these dropdowns are changed.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boBNKp

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div class="profiler">
      <div class="in">
        <div class="profiler__form">
          <div class="profiler__form--row">
            <span>I'm visiting for a </span>
            <dropdown @menu-tags="menuTags" @prev-array="previousArray" v-bind:dropdown="visiting">Special Occasion</dropdown>
          </div>
          <div class="profiler__form--row">
            <span>I'm interested in</span>
            <!-- Pass down to child a custom event listener called is-menu-visible and assign 
               to a function called isMenuVisible (See dropdown.vue) -->
            <dropdown @menu-tags="menuTags" @prev-array="previousArray" v-bind:dropdown="interestedOne">The Spa</dropdown>
            <span>and</span>
            <dropdown @menu-tags="menuTags" @prev-array="previousArray" v-bind:dropdown="interestedTwo">Exploring</dropdown><br><br>{{watchCurrent}} <span>-- BUILD THIS BASED ON ALL DROPDOWNS
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: How is this different from the question two days ago?

Comment: I am working directly with a child component. Three instances of the same child component. I want to individualise these and append to an array. Two days ago I wasn't working with these. So what I am asking is what do I need to pass back and forth in order to find a solution.

I could do this with normal select boxes that arent child components.